# How to NSLog the contents of core data database

Tags: iphone, core-data

In my app I am using `coredata` to store details about the document

Here's my code

```
-(void)writeToDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)newdocument
    {
     Images *image =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Images" inManagedObjectContext:newdocument.managedObjectContext];  
      image.album = @"Album 1";
      image.date = @"October";
      image.share = @"Not shared yet"; }
```

In the above code

```
    1.Images is the core data entity.

    2.I have inserted data in this fashion(temporarily) just to check.
```

How can I `NSLog` the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Assume the attribute values in the coredata are Strings

```
 NSLog(@"Image Name %@",image.album);
 NSLog(@"Data %@",image.date);
 NSLog(@"Share Name %@",image.share);
```

Hope it helps.